# Why is a database access much faster on SSD even when everything fits into main memory?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, mysql, cache

By a mistake a wrote a piece of code which fetched 1000 table rows one by one instead of at once. It was tested on four pretty *idle* Linux machines running mysql: two of them using an HDD and two using an SSD. In the first case it took about three times as long as in the second (2 vs. 6 milliseconds per row). There were other hardware differences, but the HDD computers were otherwise better than the other two.

Obviously, SSD is much faster, but there were *no database writes*, the code piece was *repeated* many times and there was *more than enough RAM* to buffer everything.

So I'm asking if there's a disk access necessary and why?

Comment: Have you checked out this question on Database Administrators? [https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/59828/ssd-vs-hdd-for-databases](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/59828/ssd-vs-hdd-for-databases) I know it doesn't explicitly answer your question, but it might lead you in the right direction.

Comment: I'm wondering if it could be related to what you say such as "There were other hardware differences"... So if there are other hardware differences than just one server using SSD and another using other types, then perhaps that's why there is a difference? Just a thought without any research and based only on your question wording.

Comment: @Cown I There are good arguments in favor of SSD, but there's no mention about my situation: Repeatedly reading a rather small data set which easily fits in memory. This should effectively remove any disk timing from the equation.

Comment: **Hey closers, what's wrong with this question? Is it forbidden to ask if a disk access is necessary when everything can and should be actually buffered?**

Comment: @McDonald's It's not like it were two computers of a one kind and two of the other kind, but rather four "randomly chosen" instances. Except for one: One of them is the smallest available virtual host from the hosting service. It happens to have an SSD and belongs to the fast group.

Comment: Sorry for all the comments and I will clean these up and delete soon but as a DBA personally I know too well that you're always going to have query performance differences between two systems unless both are 100% identical configuration from MySQL, OS, Hardware, Network, etc. I would guess there's more at play here than just the SSD differences and everything being loaded to RAM and not disk that affect your query performance differences across the multiple instances of MySQL.

Comment: @McDonald's Thank you for answering! Only local network, all databases run locally and the reported time is for the set of queries alone. MySQL has its default configuration. I'm thinking about everything what could possibly be relevant, but despite the differences, I can't think about anything being able to cause a **factor of three** difference. Three of the computers are hosted somewhere and I won't be able to get at the data. If the difference was like factor 1.5, I'd say that it all may matter, but actually the most expensive machine is 3x slower than the cheapest one (the same provider).

Comment: Are the hosted machines VPSes? That would make their "hardware" radically different from a physical machine. And also might mean the "machines" RAM is actually shared. In that case, even if the entire database was already loaded into "memory," the hypervisor might have moved some of it (any thing it considers "idle") to swap to make more RAM available for other VPSes on the same physical machine... thus necessitating retrieving your "RAM" from the file system when you suddenly need all of it all at once.

Comment: @CliffArmstrong One slow machine is a "root server" (only ours), one fast machine is a "virtual server" (shared), so what you wrote could happen easily in *the opposite direction*. It was no glitch, the speed ratio is rather constant (now observed again). The query was executed every few seconds in both cases and touches only a small part of the database (the whole database has a few hundred MB only and the slow machine has 16 GB total, at the moment are 5 GB free according to `top`).

Comment: My next thought would have been that your physical machines are configured with an aggressive swapping policy (not ideal for servers), but with it executing the query every few seconds that wouldn't matter. I'll let you know if I think of anything else.